# openSuse - /lib/modules/6.1.10-1-default/build not found

Tags: opensuse

Upon installing droidcam on my system, I have the following problem, after I installed the droidcam-client, which worked without any issues.

```
    sudo ./install-video
    [sudo] Passwort für root: 
    Webcam parameters: '640' and '480'
    Building v4l2loopback-dc.ko
    make: Entering directory '/home/kevin/Downloads/droidcam/v4l2loopback'
    make -C /lib/modules/6.1.10-1-default/build M=/home/kevin/Downloads/droidcam/v4l2loopback modules
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/kevin/Downloads/droidcam/v4l2loopback'
    make[1]: *** /lib/modules/6.1.10-1-default/build: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden.  Stop.

    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kevin/Downloads/droidcam/v4l2loopback'
    make: *** [Makefile:8: all] Error 2
    make: Leaving directory '/home/kevin/Downloads/droidcam/v4l2loopback'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, as I am afraid of breaking things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the `kernel-default-devel` rpm package is missing. Ideally it should be same rpm version as the running `kernel-default`.